# As of 2017, can I file 1040NR or 1040NR-EZ online?

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, electronic-filing

Is there a service that is currently able to file the US tax forms 1040NR or 1040NR-EZ electronically? I have moved out of the US so any online service that helps me with paper-filing the tax forms across the world would be really helpful.

Comment: Turbotax? Not sure if they do nr though

Comment: As of 2020, Turbotax does *not* provide support for the 1040NR or the 1040NR-EZ.

Answer (score 2):

I *believe* TaxAct (whom I use, but have no affiliation with otherwise) will let you file the 1040NR electronically.

See https://www.taxact.com/support/19030/2016/form-1040nr-and-form-1040nr-ez for details.

Comment: +1 - I filed a 1040NR last year with TaxAct. I couldn't submit it online because of complications with my return (foreign income, lack of an SSN/ITIN for my wife), but they most certainly _claimed_ I could file it online. Be warned: If you have to print your tax return and mail it in, TaxAct charges an additional fee _per return_. I had to pay for three returns, which ended up being around $100 in total. Still cheaper than getting an accountant though.