# E-filing US tax returns

Tags: united-states, taxes

I want to e-file my US tax returns that I have prepared myself. I don't see any link specifically dedicated to e-file. All I see is https://www.irs.gov/filing/e-file-options  I have already prepared my return and so I don't need further help in this regard. I just want to know where I can e-file. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4):

One of the options is Free File Fillable Forms, which consist of online forms which look almost exactly like the paper forms, which you can fill out based on the paper forms that you filled out, and e-file for free, regardless of your level of income.

(Note: this is only for federal tax returns. Whether your state has similar free online fillable forms depends on your state.)

Comment: Can you send a link to them? Thank you.

Comment: @user2371765: On that page you linked to, go to the first link, then click the second button, then click the button, and you will get to https://www.freefilefillableforms.com/

Comment: I did not see 1040NR there..

Comment: @user2371765: I didn't know you were a nonresident alien, but yes, 1040NR cannot be filed using Free File Fillable Forms.

Comment: Do you know anything that does 1040NR? I tried Turbotax, but it did 1040 for me. It never even considered that I could be a non-resident.

Comment: @user2371765: Some schools have deals with certain products like Glacier or Sprintax that handle nonresident returns, but they are not free. A few previous questions ([here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/74811/as-of-2017-can-i-file-1040nr-or-1040nr-ez-online) and [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/75751/how-to-e-file-1040nr-ez)) about e-filing 1040NR have gotten TaxAct as an answer, but that is not free either. If you want to do it for free, paper filing might be the only option.

Comment: Yes, the IRS software identified TaxAct for me yesterday. Thank you. I might pay if I get the expected results because I just realized that I used 1040 and that I need to use 1040NR.